# Gap in parallaxing background loop

Tags: xna, c#, parallax-scrolling

The bug here is that my background kind of offset a bit itself from where it should draw and so I have this line. I have some troubles understanding why I get this bug when I set a speed that is different then 1,2,4,8,16,...

[image]

In main class I set the speed depending on the player speed

```
 bgSpeed = -(int)playerMoveSpeed.X / 10;
```

and here's my background class

```
class ParallaxingBackground
    {
        Texture2D texture;
        Vector2[] positions;
        public int Speed { get; set;}

        public void Initialize(ContentManager content, String texturePath, int screenWidth, int speed)
        {
            texture = content.Load<Texture2D>(texturePath);
            this.Speed = speed;
            positions = new Vector2[screenWidth / texture.Width + 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < positions.Length; i++)
            {
                positions[i] = new Vector2(i * texture.Width, 0); 
            }
        }
        public void Update() {
            for (int i = 0; i < positions.Length; i++)
            {
                positions[i].X += Speed;
                if (Speed <= 0)
                {
                    if (positions[i].X <= -texture.Width)
                    {
                        positions[i].X = texture.Width * (positions.Length - 1);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (positions[i].X >= texture.Width*(positions.Length - 1))
                    {
                        positions[i].X = -texture.Width;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < positions.Length; i++)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(texture, positions[i], Color.White);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem happens when you reuse the background and put it the other side. Change this:

```
 if (positions[i].X <= -texture.Width)
 {
      positions[i].X = texture.Width * (positions.Length - 1);
 }
```

To this:

```
 if (positions[i].X <= -texture.Width)
 {
      positions[i].X += texture.Width * positions.Length;
 }
```

So, add (`+=`) instead of overwrite (`=`).

Same here, change this:

```
if (positions[i].X >= texture.Width*(positions.Length - 1))
{
     positions[i].X = -texture.Width;
}
```

To this:

```
if (positions[i].X >= texture.Width*(positions.Length - 1))
{
     positions[i].X -= texture.Width * positions.Length;
}
```

Don't forget to get rid of the `- 1` two times.